# What is the relative importance of the Coriolis term to the precession term in frame dragging by rotating Kerr black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, coriolis-effect, precession, kerr-metric, frame-dragging

The Wikipedia entry for [Thirring precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession) describes the Coriolis term as separate from the precession term.  Is it fair to say that when looking at the dynamics of a rotating black hole, the Coriolis term is very important (things falling towards the black hole follow a geodesic and end up circling it) whereas the precession term is not really that critical (who cares if the particles are spinning?).  Or is it wrong to say that the two terms can be separated like that?